# Accessing items in a ListView

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2012, xamarin

I am writing a speech-recognition program which displays its results in a `ListView`. What I want to accomplish is allowing a click on an item (a recognition result) to result in a request to Google Translation engine, and getting back the translated result.

What I'm not sure of is how to make the items in the `ListView` clickable so that I can add the translation code.

Here is what I have so far:

```
IList<String> matches = data.GetStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraResults);
voice_list.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, matches);
```

What do I need to add in order to make the items in the `ListView` clickable?

Comment: please refer android documentation before starting a project or working on an existing project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In java I would write

```
voice_list.setOnItemClickListner(...)
```

so in xamaring this method should also exist.

However there is more C#-ish way:

```
voice_list.ItemClick += delegate(object sender, ItemEventArgs args)
       {
        // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text  
        // do what you want
       };
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir, it s working :D

I just changed one thing:

    voice_list.ItemClick += delegate(object sender, Android.Widget.AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs args)
                    {
                        Toast.MakeText(this, "test", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                    };


Can You please tell me how I can get the text in the item??

for example when I say "no" it recongnises (now, know, you know....)

thank you